# Python- Panda dataframe: Find value in Column X based on nearest value in Column Y

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, find

I need the code that worked with this issue:
Let assume I have DataFrame named as Data.
Data has three columns, X,Y and Z

[image]

```py
index=[0,1,2] X=[1,3,5] Y=[1,4,8] Z=[3,4,7]
```

I want a code that able to find the value of X when the nearest value of Y is 2.

So that **the answer return to be X=1**,   as nearest value of Y=2 is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY:

```
import numpy as np
near_val = 5
result = df.loc[df['Y'] == df.Y.values.flat[np.abs(df.Y.values - near_val).argmin()]]['X’].values
```

Comment: The code works well thank you, but they're a little thing. When I print "result", it came up with the index number and this statement (Name: X, dtype: float64,)

What I want to do is to find 6 values, 
So, I should have [result 1, result 2, result 3, result 4, result 5, result 6] and then find the mean, max, and mini in those 6 values? any idea?

Comment: @Husa use `.values` it’ll return the underlying numpy array and you can access the element as you do in a normal Python list.